# iPhone SQLite Crash sqlite3_last_insert_rowid or sqlite3_close.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sqlite

I'm having two crashes show up in my logs using the following code to insert into my SQLite DB - the code works perfectly most of the time however clearly there is a something wrong that's causing the crash.

It crashes on either sqlite3_last_insert_rowid or sqlite3_close with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (I hold a reference to the SMSDatabase and it's in a singleton not sure why it would be deallocated) and SIGABRT (memory issue?)

```
- (NSInteger)query:(NSString *)query {

    NSInteger lastRowID = 0;

        if (sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &smsDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
        {                
            sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;

            const char *sql = [query UTF8String];

            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(smsDatabase, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

                if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                {
                    lastRowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(smsDatabase);
                }
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }

    sqlite3_close(smsDatabase);

    return lastRowID;
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: :i have the same problem can you tell me how can you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3_close(smsDatabase); - isn't this outside your if statement, which means you are closing a database which may have never been opened ?

Comment: The [documentaton](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) says: "Whether or not an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated with the database connection handle should be released by passing it to sqlite3_close() when it is no longer required."